# Complex numbers and simple argument question

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, coordinate-systems

Yesterday, i encountered a question:

> $z=a+bi$
>
> $Arg(z-\overline z + 4) = {4\pi \over 3}$
>
> $b=?$

I solved the question using basic method:
$$\overline z = a-bi$$
$$ w = z - \overline z + 4$$
$$ w = a+bi-(a-bi)+4 $$
$$ w = 4 + 2bi $$
$$ Arg(w) = {4\pi \over 3}$$
$$ \frac{Im(w)}{Re(w)} = \tan {4\pi \over 3} $$
$$ {2bi \over 4} = \sqrt 3 $$
$$ b = 2 \sqrt 3 $$
But I think there is a problem here. $4\pi\over 3$ is on the third region, so a complex number in 3rd region have both Real an Imaginary parts negative.
So I'm thinking $Re(w), Im(w)<0$
The teacher said $Arg(z)$ and $Arg(z-z_0)$ are different things, but I really can't figure out that.

Am I right or the question is true?

Comment: It is true that arg $arg(z-z_0)$ why? Consider a point $z_0 = 2+2i$ and $z=1+i$ , It is in Quad 1 but $(z-z_0)=-1-i$ is in quad 3.

Comment: So you're saying $Arg(w)$ and $Arg(z-z_0)$ are different things that gives different results?

Comment: if $\arg{w}=\frac{4\pi}{3}$ this means $\mathcal{Re}{w}\lt 0$ and in our case it is $4$ So no matter the value of $b$ there is no such $z$